# Loading a configuration for Unity from an external assembly

Tags: c#, configuration, unity-container

I'm trying to load config settings for Unity from another assembly named 'Config', however I'm not having much in the way of luck.

```
var fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("assembly://Config/Config/Unity.config"); 
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = onfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap as ExeConfigurationFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var unitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)configuration.GetSection("unity");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get any error? Which of your posted steps fails? Your question is a bit vague, please add some more details.

Comment: The issue is that the casting of the fileMap to ExeConfigurationFileMap always returns null, so I can't seem to get the resource out of the assembly as a config object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a workaround.

In your code:

```
  var container = new UnityContainer();
            var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UnityPath"].ToString();
            var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            map.ExeConfigFilename = path; 
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("unity");
```

And in your config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="UnityPath" value="C:\PathToYourConfigFile\Unity.Config"/>
  </appSettings>
```